# Proof that $t_n$ with $t_n= u_n - u_{n+1}$ is also a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

When following data are given;

$u_n$ is a aritmetical series with common difference $v$.

Proof that the series $t_n$ with $u_n- u_{n+1}$ is also an arithmetical series **AND** find the common diffrence $v_2$ of series $t_n$.

Comment: Hint: if $v$ is the common difference what is $u_n-u_{n+1}=-(u_{n+1}-u_n)$?

Comment: owh thanks .. i feel kinda stupid now hahaha :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $u_n$ is an arithmetic sequence, $u_n = vn+w$ for some value $w$. Then
$$
t_n = u_n-u_{n+1} = (vn+w)-(v(n+1)+w) = -v
$$
so $t_n$ is a constant sequence, so it's also an arithmetic sequence with common difference $0$.